# Does a resource have to be within the fat plus to use?

Tags: civilization-4

In Civilization IV, can I connect to a resource outside of the "fat plus" as long as it is inside my civilization boundaries?

For instance, could I build a road and pasture to horses three tiles away from a city and then be able to produce horse archers?

```
.......    C: city
H...C..    H: horses
.......    .: other tile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can train horse req. units when the horses are within your borders, and your workers have build on it.
- You cannot train horse req. units when the horses are outside your borders, and have not been build by your workers.

[image]

From GameFAQs:

> Once improved, the resource is not accessible until you have connected
>   it with  your settled areas. The resource will be available to any
>   city that is  CONNECTED to it -- your cities will not automatically
>   gain the resource unless  it is part of your empire's network. That
>   means by road, railroad, river,  harbour or airport. If that confuses
>   you, consider the following scenario:
>
> - Beijing is connected by road to a Horse pasture (i.e. improved tile).
> - Shanghai is not connected to Beijing.
>
> In this scenario, if the player wanted to create Horse Archers, they
>   can only  do so in Beijing -- Shanghai CANNOT train Horse Archers
>   because it does not  have access to the necessary resource. In order
>   for Shanghai to train Horse  Archers, it must be connected to Beijing.
>   Rivers count as transportation  networks, so cities located on the
>   same river automatically share the resource.  Settlements on different
>   continents must be connected by a Harbor. Researching  Flight and
>   building Airports will also distribute the resource. Offshore 
>   resources (e.g. Fish, Whale) will be connected to coastal cities, but
>   those  cities will need land or air connections to share the resource
>   with inland  cities.
>
> *(source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/919352-sid-meiers-civilization-iv/faqs/51629)*

Comment: In the screencap, the horses are within the "fat plus" (workable squares) of Pataliputra. Would it work if that city had been built a square to the right, too? (And it was still within the cultural borders, of course)

Comment: @Anna I updated the answer with a ref. to a Game FAQ

Comment: Thanks. So if I had a single city with huge cultural borders, I could connect it to horses five tiles away as long as I built a pasture and roads and it was all within the cultural borders?

Comment: @Anna Yes! If it was within your City borders, it would add production to your city. Those tiles within City borders benifit the City.

Comment: When you cut-and-paste content, use a quote block to indicate that you're using someone else's words.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I didn't know. Thanks for the edit though.

Comment: @AtlasEU No problem! You cited your source, so it was an easy fix.